# Displaying image when button clicked

Tags: ios, xcode, button, keyboard

I've build this keyboard and in the picture you can see it, it's the number 1 but I want to it become number 2.

I write with taking the title of every button so button A is titled A and when clicked it will display A in the large label that I have over those empty boxes, the empty boxes are UIview.

Does someone knows in which way to get this working do I have to use different layers? or whatever because I don't know.

hope someone can tell me here is the picture:

http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/4500/questionow.png

thanks

**EDIT**

This is what I got now    .h

```
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview1;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview2;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview3;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview4;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview5;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview6;
}

-(IBAction)showA;
-(IBAction)showB;
-(IBAction)showC;
-(IBAction)showD;
-(IBAction)showE;
-(IBAction)showF;
-(IBAction)showG;
-(IBAction)showH;
-(IBAction)showI;
-(IBAction)showJ;
-(IBAction)showK;
-(IBAction)showL;
-(IBAction)showM;
-(IBAction)showN;
-(IBAction)showO;
-(IBAction)showP;
-(IBAction)showQ;
-(IBAction)showR;
-(IBAction)showS;
-(IBAction)showT;
-(IBAction)showU;
-(IBAction)showV;
-(IBAction)showW;
-(IBAction)showX;
-(IBAction)showY;
-(IBAction)showZ;
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)showA {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"A.png"];

[imageview1 setImage:img];

}

-(IBAction)showB {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"B.png"];

[imageview1 setImage:img];  

}
```

Etc.

got UIImageview over the empty box and the first letters are shown very nice

Watched some tutorials on mutable arrays but still not sure how to implant it in my code.

Would it be a mutable array with imagevie1, 2,3,4,5,6?

hope you can help me out again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more about organizing your thoughts than actually technical stuff.

1) Check how many boxes are filled, so you know what's the next box to be filled.

2) Have a way to access each box.

**Edit 1: Building the Data Source**

This is just a way to get your started:

1) Start by creating an NSMutableArray.

2) When you click any button, using the size of your NSMutableArray, you can automatically know where the image should be placed:

```
myArray count = 0 => UIImageView 0 needs to be filled
myArray count = 1 => UIImageView 1 needs to be filled
myArray count = 2 => UIImageView 2 needs to be filled
myArray count = 3 => UIImageView 3 needs to be filled
```

Comment: Yeah I know been thinking about it a lot but Can't really find the right way, I think they all have to be different layers right but then I don't know the code that the second box will be filled ones the first one is already filled

Comment: You can have a data source that handles that for you, an array for example. If it's size is 0, then the index 0 needs an image. If it's size is 1, then index 1 needs an image...

Comment: Do you have a sample code for me? or can I find that anywhere

Comment: and then change the UIview empty box to button pressed or does it have to over it or something copy it and place button there?

Comment: If you only want to show the image, why not an UIImageView? Just check the UIImage of the button you pressed, calculate the place where you should place it, and use that same UIImage to set the UIImageView's image.

Comment: So I would do when button A pressed change empty box 1 to UIView button A, I don't know the code that will see that box is filled so the next button clicked will be displayed in box 2.